# javascript not displaying output when content loaded via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login page that runs a script from a third-party site as so:

```
<span id="siteseal">
    <script src="https://seal.starfieldtech.com/getSeal?sealID=myspecialid"></script>
</span>
```

Everything is hunky dory.  It performs some javascript and eventually displays an image.

I recently moved it to a separate file, and am including it in the original page using

```
$('#mydivid').load('/mypath/footer.html');
```

The entire footer is displayed, and in chrome developer tools I can see that the request is made to starfieldtech and a javascript response is returned, but the image is never displayed.

The getSeal script is pretty simple, looking something like:

```
<!--
doSomething();

function doSomething() {
    // setup a bunch of vars
    document.write('<img src="blah" onclick="doStuffOnClick();"/>');
}

function doStuffOnClick() {
    // do other stuff on click.
}
// -->
```

If I create my own script that looks very similar to the above then it replaces the whole page with the output of my script and also shows the intended starfield image.

I have no clue what the problem is and hope the gurus can point out something stupid I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but in a general sense you shouldn't be trying to use `document.write()` after the page is loaded. You're using jQuery anyway, so why not something like `$('<img src="blah"/>',{click:doStuffOnClick}).appendTo('#someParent');`?

Comment: if the code being returned is the code listed then it's commented out and it won't do anything. btw you're mixing html comments with js comments. could that be the problem?

Comment: @dolphonebubleine That's how they did scripts in the "olden days" so that those browsers that didn't support javascript wouldn't show the script text.  I don't think it's used much anymore.

Comment: I believe people still comment script out so that the page validates correctly. Only a few of the older browsers actually need it commented for display purposes - the new ones are smart enough to not display `script` content as text, just not smart enough to validate the page correctly.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Douglas. I don't do a lot of javascript... obviously.

Comment: Just in case, you misspelled the closing script tag. Also, as others have pointed out, using the load method makes the insertion asynchronous, and cant be used with document.write

Comment: @Ian good catch. That was a copy/paste problem when I was trying to format it in the post.  The rest is good information. Sadly, sounds like I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: @ian [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) says "any JavaScript loaded into [an element] as a part of the document will successfully execute". I haven't tested, but are you sure `document.write` wont work? Am I misreading the API?

Answer (score 1):

As you can't edit the javascipt returned by starfieldtech.com, I think the only sensible way round this is to use phantom.js (or similar) to pre-process third party html on your server before sending to the browser

Comment: interesting idea, I'll have to do some looking at phantom.js. Thanks for the pointer.